# Regex for something not between quotes and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the word `hello` that is not between any type of quote (`''` or `""` or ``` `` ```) and not in parentheses.

An example match would be:

```
'hello'(hello)('hello')hello
                       ^^^^^ # the last hello is matched
```

If there is any way to do something like this I would appreciate it. Thanks!

What i have tried is this:

```
'(hello)+(?=(?:[^\'"`]*[\'"`][^\'"`]*[\'"`])*[^\'"`]*$)(?!\()(?<!\))'
```

but it always returns nothing as a match

I am trying to get the index of the match.

Comment: Which language/regex engine? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Language? Tool?

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: @the try `(?<![('"\`])hello(?!['"\`)])`

Comment: Does this have to be regex?  Seems like the solution would be easier to understand and maintain if you wrote a generator function to return substrings that aren't inside quotes, then you could scan the substrings for the target string.

Comment: If you need to replace, you just need to use something like ``s.replace(/(`[^`]*`|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')|hello/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1 : "<b>" + $0 + "</b>" })``

Comment: I would prefer regex, but if there is a way with loops that would also be helpful

Comment: What is the point of matching "hello"?  If you already know it's "hello", don't you already know what it is?

Comment: Hello is just a placeholder for another phrase

Comment: Another way of doing this would be to get the indexes of every instance of the target string ("hello" in this case), then count the number of parenthesis that came before it.  If its odd, its in the quotes.  Even, it isn't.  This would probably be the easiest to understand and maintain, but I suppose it wouldn't perform as well.

Comment: You didn't mention it, but I suppose brackets that appear *within* quotes, do not count.

Comment: @trincot yes that is true

Comment: ...and the same type of brackets can be nested? Like `((((a)))hello)`?

Comment: yes I know nesting isn't regex's best trait, but if there is a way, that would be amazing

Comment: Does it really have to be a regex solution? Nesting is then out of the question, as recursive regexes are not (yet) supported in JavaScript.

Comment: If you can make a solution with loops, that would also be very helpful

Comment: In PCRE regex engines you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/G4PkoY/1) `(?:\((['"\`])(?:(?!\1).)+\1\)|(['"\`])(?:(?!\2).)+\2|(\((?:(?3)|[^()])*\)))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^'"\`(]+`, but JavaScript is quite limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression is not really the right tool for this. Moreover, JavaScript does not (at this moment) support `(?R)`-recursion logic, so for supporting nested parentheses detection, it would be better to use a plain old `for` loop.

Here is a function that does the job. It is run with the example input and word you have provided and it returns the index at which it finds a good match -- in this case 23:

```js
function findOccurrence(input, word) {
    for (let i = 0, j = -1, nesting = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let ch = input[i];
        if (i > j) {
            j = input.indexOf(word, i); // find next occurrence of word
            if (j < 0) return -1; // no more occurrences...
        }
        if (i === j && nesting === 0) return i; // bingo!
        if ("`'\"".includes(ch)) { // opening quote
            i = input.indexOf(ch, i+1); // jump to closing quote (of same type)
        } else if (ch === "(") {
            nesting++;
        } else if (nesting > 0 && ch === ")") {
            nesting--;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}

// example:
console.log(findOccurrence("'hello'(hello)('hello')hello", "hello"));
```